# How to override the html.tlp.php file in bartik

Tags: php, drupal, theming

Hi I am using a modified bartik theme, and I want to change around the body.

I've been trying to change it using variations of the following, since that's what most of the doc. says to do, but it doesn't work.

```
function bartik_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__node__7';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `bartik theme` folder there is a `function` named `bartik_process_page(&$variables)` .But I have to say try copying your `theme` to the `sites/themes` folder if you have to change or alter any `theme`.Inside this function place the `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]` and specify the required `tpl.php file` for your purpose.For example

```
function bartik_process_page(&$variables) {

   $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__test'; //Place your code here
```

I have a file named `html--test.tpl.php` in my `bartik` folder.Try clearing the `cache` and run. :)

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. Maybe not using a subtheme has something to do with it. I know it's not the best practice but shouldn't it work regardless? I have successful overridden page.tpl.php but html.tpl.php no such luck.

Comment: Thank you, yes this worked, but only after I created my own subtheme.